# IBDataset, how/when is RefreshSQL executed?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm using Delphi 2010 IBDataset component. I have fields in my query that come from a joined table that is not included in the update sql. So i need the row i've updated to be refreshed. The SQL needed to do this is in the updateSQL property of the IBDataset.

How and when do i invoke this update SQL? I assume it must be done after i have committed the update.

I thought i would just need to invoke IBDataset.Update but that has no effect.